# I cant copy files using streams

Tags: c#

I have a function to  copy files using streams .I think I messed up everything because whenever try to exacute this code My computer freezes..Can you please help

I have also tried to use `Using` statements .But It s getting more comlplicated

```
void CopyFiles(string path, string savepath)
{
    FileStream fsopen = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int count = fsopen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    fsopen.Close();

    FileStream fsw = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    while (count > 0)
    {
        fsw.Write(buf, 0, count);
    }

    fsw.Close();
    fsw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: `while (count > 0)` runs forever since you're never decrementing `count`.

Comment: The while loop must encompass the Read() as well. And there is always Stream.CopyTo(), cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Oh, and DO use using because Streams are Disposables. You can then omit he Close()s and you are exception safe.

Comment: You really should try stepping through your code in debugger to see what it actually does.

Comment: Unless you are doing something special during this process, you should be using [System.IO.File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
void CopyFiles(string path, string savepath)
{
    FileStream fsopen = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    FileStream fsw = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    int count = 0;
    while ((count=fsopen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length))>0)
    {
        fsw.Write(buf, 0, count);
    }

    fsw.Flush();
    fsw.Close();
}
```

Comment: That excatly what i want

Answer (score 2):

You have made a infinite loop whth the `while(count > 0)`.

You know the length of the data you want to write, but you must read again of the length max of the buffer

```
FileStream fsw = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
int count = 0;
do
{
    count = fsopen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    if (count > 0)
        fsw.Write(buf, 0, count);
}
while (count > 0)
```

and don't forget to close the streams when you have done.

Answer (score 2):

As @Frédéric Hamidi pointed out, the While loop while (count > 0) will run forever as you aren't incrementing count to make it greater than 0.

Secondly, you are only reading the first kb of the file, closing the file, then writing the first kb of the file to another file.

```
using (FileStream source = File.Open(@"c:\temp\data.dat",
   FileMode.Open))
 {

   // Copy source to destination.
   source.CopyTo(destination);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Read in a loop:

```
FileStream fsopen = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

FileStream fsw = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
int count = 0;

do  
{
    count = fsopen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    fsw.Write(buf, 0, count);

} (while count > 0)

fsopen.Close();
```

Or just use `File.Copy()` or `Stream.CopyTo()`.

Comment: I see. Learned something (and deleted my previous comments).